# SSIS job on sql server running a different version of Interop.Excel

Tags: ssis, ssms

I have a SSIS job that was built with SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2012, and the job runs without any problems. The reference in the project is set as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel version 14. However, when I deploy and run it on SSMS SQL Sever 2012, it would prompt an error

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicToken='

Is there anywhere I can set the Interop.Excel version used in SSMS?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add *Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll* to the GAC at `C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\` on the server the SSIS package is running.

I have Excel 2010 and Version 14 so my path is slightly different but here is an example:

`C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel\14.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll`